# Riemann Integral defined as limit of Riemann sum

Tags: integration

In my math course I was told the following 
Let $f$ be a function defined on $[a;b] \subset \mathbb{R}$ 
We partition this interval in $n$ smaller intervals : 
$$[x_0,x_1],[x_1,x_2]...[x_i,x_{i+1}],[x_{n-1},x_n]$$
we define $h$ the length of these intervals : $$h=\frac{b-a}{n}$$
then $$x_n=a+nh$$
It is also clear that when $n$ tends to $+ \infty$, $h$ tends to 0
$hf(x_i)$
is the area of a rectangle under a curve drawn above the text

We define $S_n=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} h f(x_i)$$

then we say that $f$ is integrable if 
$$\exists ! l=\lim_{n\to \infty} S_n \in \mathbb{R}$$
and we represent this as $$l=\int_a^b f(x) dx $$ 
We admitted that
1. all continuous functions are integrable
2. $f\geq g \implies \int_a^b f(x) dx \geq \int_a^b g(x) dx \,  f,g $ are integrable functions on this interval
3. $\int_a^b f(x) dx + \int_b^c f(x) dx = \int_a^c f(x) dx $
Can anyone help me proving these properties ?
I'm stuck after the epsilon definition of the limit.
Thanks
Tom

Comment: These are basic exercises Where are you having trouble? (By the way - this is called the "Cauchy Integral", and it is used only where the author doesn't mind restricting everything to be continuous, as this definition of integration has poor properties when discontinuous functions are examined.)

Answer (score 0):

Let $f$ and $g {\in}R[a,b]$ .Let $p$ be a partition such that $P=[X0,X1],.......[Xn-1,Xn]$. Suppose $X_0=a$ and $X_n=b$.let $f$ and $g$ continuous and $f≥g$ then $g(x)-F(x)≤0$ so $g(x)-f(x) \in R[a, b]$ then ${\int_a^b(g(x)-f(x)}={\int_a^{X1}(g(x)-f(x))+\int_X1^{X2}(g(x)-f(x))...........\int_Xn-1^b(g(x)) -f(x))} ≤ 0(b-a)$  so $\int_{a}^{X_1}(g) + \int_{x_1}^{x_2}(g)+.......+ \int_{x_n-1}^{b}(g) - \int_{a}^{X_1}(f) \int_{x_1}^{x_2}(f)+........+ \int_{x_n-1}^{b}(f)) \le 0$ so ${\int _a^b(g) -\int_a^b(f) ≤0}$

Comment: Please format your answer for latex